Is the sun multinucleated or is there just one point at or near the center of the sun where fusion is occurring?
I was just reflecting upon my thinking and probably any illustration in books or movies: I assumed a single general area near the "geographical" center where the actual fusion occurs.
But why would not one reaction perhaps trigger further reactions and so rather than fusion occurring at one small, dense region perhaps it occurs in many areas with the dense center being favored?
I guess I do not want to limit the question to our own sun only: if it is known that some stars have many cores and others are limited to a single core, that would be of interest.

The stackexchange webpage has a column 'Related' with a list of earlier questions. One of those questions is titled Where is nuclear fusion occurring in the Sun The answer there covers your question well.
